# Is reference partitioning suitable for filtering result set based on content of referenced tables?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, partitioning, database-partitioning

I am using Oracle 11g. I have a messages table with about a billion records that is range partitioned on timestamp. This messages table has several reference partitioned sub tables such as names, addresses, and identifications.

All queries include the messages timestamp partition key. When querying the messages table on only message fields it works fine and I can pull info from my sub tables, but I am experiencing poor performance for queries that look for messages containing a certain name or address or other value from these reference partitioned sub tables.

When analyzing these queries and going over their plans I see that it is doing a full partition scan on the sub table prior to accessing the message table. I am able to improve the performance of these queries by using the leading hint and having the query begin with the message table, but I don't like having to use hints and even with it the performance still isn't great.

My concern now is that the reference partition model may simply not be a good fit for my needs and that I would need to move to a different partitioning model. I am looking to confirm if reference partitioning is not designed for filtering by a referenced tables data. I have been over a lot of the Oracle documentation and I can't find any mention of it, so I am still not certain enough to go forward with this costly migration.

---

I was hoping someone would know right off whether this was true or not and point to some documentation I somehow missed. But now that I'm being asked to provide example queries and plans, which is certainly reasonable, I will have to add more information I left out. In addition to being range partitioned, the message table is also sub partitioned on a varchar column.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM EVT_TRANS_MSG A, EVT_TRANS_MSG_ID B WHERE A.TIMESTAMP_F >= '03-OCT-13 12.00.00.000000000 AM'  AND A.TIMESTAMP_F <= '03-OCT-13 11.59.59.999000000 PM' AND B.CODE = '999999999'  AND A.ID = b.message_fk AND a.object_type = 'BLAH';
```

Execution time: 529 seconds (8 minutes 49 seconds)

[image: Plan]

```
SELECT /*+ LEADING(A) */ count(*) FROM EVT_TRANS_MSG A, EVT_TRANS_MSG_ID B WHERE A.TIMESTAMP_F >= '03-OCT-13 12.00.00.000000000 AM'  AND A.TIMESTAMP_F <= '03-OCT-13 11.59.59.999000000 PM' AND B.CODE = '999999999'  AND A.ID = b.message_fk AND a.object_type = 'BLAH';
```

Execution time: 12 seconds

[image: plan with hint]

Comment: Why is performance better when the message table is accessed first? What sort of predicates apply to each table? Seeing sample queries would help.

Comment: Performance is better because it doesn't do a full partition scan, it goes to the message partition and then to the reference partition through index. Without hint it is essentially doing "select messages where id in (select id from refTbl where filter)" So it scans all partitions and finds all occurrences that match filter, and only then accesses message and uses partition.

 SELECT /*+ LEADING(A)*/ count(*) FROM MSG A, MSG_ID B
WHERE A.TIMESTAMP_F >= '03-OCT-13 12.00.00.000000000 AM'  AND A.TIMESTAMP_F <= '03-OCT-13 11.59.59.999000000 PM' AND B.CODE = '999999999' AND A.ID = b.message_fk;

Comment: Can you add the good and bad performing queries to the question, along with the execution plans?